# RESTful Web API implementation to save Office documents remotely

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ms-word, ms-office

I'd like to implement somehow an endpoint on a .NET core WebAPI that allow a user to edit an Office document that he has beforehand downloaded and automatically opened in office from my WebAPI, and save it directly from the Office desktop client.

How could I do that ? One possibility is to DAV enable my API but I'm looking for a more lighter solution as I only want to manage opening and editing office document.

Currently my API sends the file and I'm planning to implement my web client to tells the system to open it in Office via Office URI Schema. I managed to open a word file in my Word Desktop app but I am stuck at this point and don't know how to edit and save it back.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the document was changed on client side, you would need to upload it to your server and overwrite the existing one.

Comment: Could you please share more details about your current implementation along with code snippet. Thus, it would convenient to check where you are eexactly stuck in.